# How to connect statements in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I have the following logical riddle:

> *"All cats are animals. Everything small is colorful."* 
> Which of the following assertions can be derived from this? Please justify the steps. 
>  a) All colorful cats are small animals. 
>  b) Some small cats are not colorful animals. 
>  c) All small cats are colorful animals. 
>  d) All non-colorful cats are animals that are not small.

---

I am confused because it seems to me that the statements do not match. I understand that I can use the objects in the statements like:

A: Cat;
B: Animals;
C: Small;
D: Colorful.

and write:

A->B

C->D

I also understand how to translate the statements a-d into logical statements. e.g.

a) (A&D)->(B&C)

etc. What I do not understand is how to reason / decide if this is possible with the above statements or not since I don't see a connection between A and D for instance. So I have two questions: 1. Is my approach correct or am I making a basic mistake? and 2. How can I argue to get the solution?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: It looks like you will need quantifiers to express some of these statements correctly. For example, a) all cats can be expressed as $\forall c$, where $c$ is short for cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Venn diagram
[image: ![enter image description here]

with legend

- A: animals
- T: cats
- F: colorful
- S: small

represents the premises “*All cats are animals. Everything small is colorful.*”

From the diagram, it is evident that the given premises entail conclusions (c) & (d), but not conclusions (a) & (b).

---

**Addendum** in response to the first comment below:
[image]

Deriving conclusion (d) (Line $8$) for example, from the two premises (Lines $1$ & $2$) using a Fitch-style proof (note that here, Tx, Mx, Sx, and Fx mean “x is a cat”, “x is an animal”, “x is small” and “x is colorful”, respectively) *can* involve a truth table to verify that Line $6$ is a tautological consequence of Lines $3-5.$

But your intuition is correct: truth tables *alone* are inadequate to assess the validity of [categorical arguments](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=categorical+arguments). For example, the categorical sentence “all cats are animals” is suitably formulated as the quantified sentence $\forall x [T(x)\rightarrow M(x)],$ but a truth table only admits its truth-functional form (the non-quantified sentence) $P,$ which clearly captures insufficient nuance. Although truth tables reveal whether a sentence is tautological, they don't generally reveal the validity of a sentence. (Assessing the validity of an argument means assessing the validity of its corresponding conditional sentence <premise>$\rightarrow$<conclusion>.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This helps! I will accept this as answer but my question was more in the direction: Is there a way to solve this using truth tables? The point is that I don't see any connection in the two initial statement such that I can conclude about the statements a-d. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: @2Obe No prob. I've expanded the answer.